# Too much text breaking my floats

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a list of search results, using an unordered list, each `<li>` is made up of 3 sections (floats):

http://jsfiddle.net/danmofo/fYMrL/4/

My problem is that everytime the text inside `<p>` exceeds the width of the the column, the floats cascade down the page, breaking the layout.

It's been a long day so probably *a minor error* somewhere, but I cannot see it.

Things I've tried doing when the text cascades:

- Making all elements inline
- Defining specific widths

Any help is appreciated, especially link to an article/some information about it, thanks.

Comment: Why are you using an unordered list to display this content?

Comment: We're already using an unordered list to display search results in other sections of the website, so keeping the original HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your floated elements widths, or the floats won't work predictably.

Something like

```
div.left-side{
    float: left;
    width:40%;
}

div.right-side{
    float:right;
    width:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the div under the p.  It is a block element that wants to take up a whole line.  Set the style to "display: inline" for this div.

Comment: Still produces the same issue